# Solutions to $Ax=u$ where $u$ is the eigenvector associated to $0$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in M_{3\times3} $ with eigenvalues $0, \lambda_1,\lambda_2$ (where $\lambda_i$ is non-zero).$

Are there any solutions to $A$**x**$=$**u** ?

Allow me to write down $x,u$ and it be known that they are vectors.

**My Current Thinking:**

If $Ax=u$
then $(A\cdot A)x=Au=0$

and so $x$ is in the null space of $A^2$ but since we have an eigenvalue of $0$, we cannot conclude that $x$ is in the null space of $A$.

From this point how would I continue this logic? I have a hunch that if $Ax=0$ has no solutions, then neither can $A^2x$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Note that $A^2$ has eigenvalues $0,\lambda_1^2,\lambda_2^2$.  This means that $A^2$ has a null space of dimension $1$.

However, if $Ax = u$ had a solution, then the span of $x$ and $u$ would necessarily fall into the null space of $A^2$, which would contradict the fact that the null space of $A^2$ has dimension $1$.